# how to close a buffer in intellij and/or ideavim

Tags: intellij-idea, buffer, ideavim

i'm trying out intellij+ideavim. I would like to use a workflow with no tabs, instead multiple open buffers (I see I can use `ctrl-e` to switch between them).

My issue is the only way that I found to delete a buffer (`:bd` in vim) is to do `ctrl-e`, then arrow up or down (because by default the current buffer is not the selected down in the list), then `delete`.

I'm hoping there is a shortcut or menu option which could be bound to a shortcut to close the buffer like that in a faster way?

Note that `ctrl-f4` is NOT what I'm after, as it closes the `window`, not the `buffer`.

*EDIT*: to formulate what i'd like another way, I'd like a shortcut to [remove the current file from the 'recent files' list](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206312269-How-to-remove-an-entry-from-the-Recent-Files-list).

Comment: It seems like most of the buffer controls from vim do not work in Ideavim.  That would be nice to fix and/or have a solution to.